# How to parse large json external file stored locally (~30 MB) to populate a select dropdown list avoiding long load time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am trying to parse a JSON file that has around 209,579 objects (~30MB file size) and populate those(names, and value attribute) in a dropdown menu using select-option tags. I could parse the whole file using the jquery getJSON method to parse and populate it using the traditional way of targeting the DOM element, but when I select the dropdown menu it takes too long to display the content and disables the browser for that period of time.

I have tried with a smaller dataset with ~100 objects (which is significantly less) and the page renders the dropdown fast and doesn't lag. This is the reason why I think I am having a problem because of my large JSON object dataset.

```
<!--html code-->
<h3>Select your Location:</h3>
<select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality">
</select>

//referenced from https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-json 
//(I have used the same technique)

let dropdown = document.getElementById('locality-dropdown');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose State/Province';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = 'js/city_list1.json';

fetch(url)  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = data[i].name;
          option.value = data[i].id;
          dropdown.add(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
```

I expect to render the dropdown like in the normal websites, but in my case, the browser stops responding and takes a while to load the content in the dropdown menu when I click on the dropdown.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a database and dynamically search as the user types? (debounced)

Answer (score 3):

As you've rightfully noted yourself the bottleneck in your case is the fact that you are trying to load the whole dataset at once. You should consider loading that data in pages (chunks) instead and maybe have a windowed component that loads/renders only the data that is currently displayed.

As others have noted JSON is not the best format for storing huge datasets, database is much better, even something as simple and small as [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) will do.

But if you would still prefer to proceed with JSON I'd recommend to try one of the libraries that **allow you to parse partial JSON** blocks and somewhat mimic what you would have if you went with database and paginated loading of data.

Take for example [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) (NodeJS module, but I'd imagine one can easily find something similar for every backend technology out there).

> **stream-json** is a micro-library of node.js stream components with
>   minimal dependencies for creating custom data processors oriented on
>   processing huge JSON files while requiring a minimal memory footprint.
>   It can parse JSON files far exceeding available memory. Even
>   individual primitive data items (keys, strings, and numbers) can be
>   streamed piece-wise.

```
const { chain } = require('stream-chain')

const { parser } = require('stream-json')
const { pick } = require('stream-json/filters/Pick')
const { streamValues } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamValues')

const fs = require('fs')

const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('sample.json'),
  parser(),
  pick({ filter: 'data' }),
  streamValues(),
  data => {
    const value = data.value
    return value && value.department === 'accounting' ? data : null
  }
])

let counter = 0
pipeline.on('data', () => ++counter)
pipeline.on('end', () =>
  console.log(`The accounting department has ${counter} employees.`)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

"Normal websites" don't have select field with `209,579` options. The speed here will not depend on your code but mostly on the client machine performance and connection speed. You must think alternatives here, like autocomplete feature, or maybe infinite scroll, things like that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect loading 200000 records into the browser dom to be performant in this scenario and will be a horrible experience for users - surely that must be obvious. You will need to store the data in a db or possibly array in the browser and then search that data and only return rows that match from autocomplete and then add them to a table/grid so you limiting the results. A drop down for this amount of data sounds like a problem.

As another old tip, rather build up your option data in a string and add that to the dom once instead of a 100 times using creatElement.